# RHEL 7 SSH Service START STOP RESTART

Tags: sshd

Sorry for this very basic question.

I work in a very small company as a developer and we are trying to help the infra team to setup a new environment.

We are migrating from RHEL 5 32bits to RHEL 7 64 bists.

We could install and parametrize properly the installation of SSH.

Everything works except what I will call 'output tag' when we stop, start or restart the service. See photo below for a better understanding. I mean the [OK], [FAILED] that appears on the screen after using service sshd restart for example.

The photo is just an example showing the tags.

[image]

On RHEL 5 it works flawless.

On RHEL 7 it works but I do **NOT** have the same output ([OK], [FAILED], etc)

I think I am missing something.

Did searches on google but could not find anything related to that.

Comment: And what is the question here? Edit your post to make it more clear.

Comment: I did it... how to enable the [OK], [FAILED], etc.... Thank you and sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to enable that type of output for systemd: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1148571

However, it will definitely let you know if it failed and how you can check for more information on why it failed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Back in Redhat 5 (and 6) that was the **INIT** way using `/etc/init.d`.  Redhat 7 uses **systemd** and you can spend the rest of your day searching the web and reading articles comparing their differences, pro's, con's, and so on.

you used to do

```
/etc/init.d/sshd status
/etc/init.d/sshd start
/etc/init.d/sshd stop
/etc/init.d/sshd restart

or you may be more familiar with     service sshd <start|stop|restart|status>
```

in RHEL 7 you do

```
systemctl status sshd
systemctl start sshd
systemctl stop sshd
systemctl restart sshd

service sshd <start|stop|restart|status> will also work but you'll get an info statement saying "redirecting to /bin/systemctl"
```

doing `systemctl status sshd` might give you a good idea to what is wrong; as well as looking in `/var/log/messages` for reported errors.

in RHEL 7.x (and many other linux) SSHd on the server is configured in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  You'll want to look at this file and make sure things are set properly because (a) if not then the service will fail to start and would be reported by *systemctl status* and (b) if the service did start with a green OK you still might not be able to ssh into your system.

here is the default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which is from Centos 7.6 actually but should be the exact same as RHEL 7.6; with your SSH service failing to start then you might try backing up your existing *sshd_config* to */etc/ssh/sshd_config_old* and using this one; if the sshd service still fails to start then it's not an *sshd_config* file problem as this one is the default that comes with a RHEL/Centos 7 installation and works for everyone on a new install.

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

RH5 used *SVR4 init* program to manage daemons. 
RH7 dropped *SVR4 init* and replaced it with *systemd*.

The `service` command is obsolete and you'd quit using it. `service` is now a simple wrapper around the "new" `systemctl` command (for retro-compatibility to LSB specifications).

So far as i know, `systemctl` does not support any kind of *output tags*.

If you need to check the status of a service programmatically, `systemctl` offers many "commands" to get the status of a service. E.g. `systemctl is-active sshd.service`, `systemctl is-enabled sshd.service`, `systemctl is-failed sshd.service`, `systemctl is-system-running sshd.service`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.